How can I reduce the complexity of my validations in python
I am trying to lower the complexity of my code and I use Scrutinizer to measure those values. In my code, most of the complexity is due to validations, so how can I improve them?
class gestionRegister:
#VALIDA LA 1 SECCION DEL FORMULARIO EN EL QUE PIDE LOS DATOS PERSONALES
def formulario1(page, nombre, apellido, cedula, numTelefono, correo, ubicacion, nivelUser, tipoCorreo, codigoTelefono, tipoCedula, formulario, contenedor1, contenedor2):
    #ARREGLOS
    arregloCedula = f"{tipoCedula.value}-{cedula.value}"
    arregloCorreo = f"{correo.value}{tipoCorreo.value}"
    arregloTelefono = f"{codigoTelefono.value}-{numTelefono.value}"
    global nuevoLider
    if (nombre.value == "") or (apellido.value == "") or (cedula.value == "") or (numTelefono.value == "") or (correo.value == "") or (ubicacion.value == "") or (nivelUser.value == None) or (tipoCorreo.value == None) or (codigoTelefono.value == None) or (len(nombre.value) in range(1, 3)) or (len(apellido.value) in range(1, 4)) or (len(cedula.value) in range(1, 7)) or (len(numTelefono.value) in range(1, 7)) or (len(ubicacion.value) in range(1, 3)):
        if nombre.value == "":
            nombre.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        
        if apellido.value == "":
            apellido.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        if cedula.value == "":
            cedula.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        if numTelefono.value == "":
            numTelefono.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        if correo.value == "":
            correo.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        if ubicacion.value == "":
            ubicacion.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        if nivelUser.value == None:
            nivelUser.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        if tipoCorreo.value == None:
            tipoCorreo.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        if codigoTelefono.value == None:
            codigoTelefono.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante
            page.update()
        if len(nombre.value) in range(1, 3):
            nombre.error_text = "Minimo de caracteres 3"
            page.update()
        if len(apellido.value) in range(1, 4):
            apellido.error_text = "Minimo de caracteres 4"
            page.update()
        
        if len(cedula.value) in range(1, 7):
            cedula.error_text = "Minimo de caracteres 7"
            page.update()
        
        if len(numTelefono.value) in range(1, 7):
            numTelefono.error_text = "Numero de telefono no valido"
            page.update()
        if len(ubicacion.value) in range(1, 3):
            ubicacion.error_text = "Minimo de caracteres 3"
            page.update()
    elif db.verificarUbicacion(ubicacion.value):
        page.snack_bar = SnackBar(content=Text("Esta ubicacion ya esta en uso"))
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        page.update()
    elif db.verificarCedula(arregloCedula):
        page.snack_bar = SnackBar(content=Text("Esta cedula ya esta ligada a un usuario"))
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        page.update()
    elif db.verificarTelefono(arregloTelefono):
        page.snack_bar = SnackBar(content=Text("Este numero de telefono ya esta asignado a un usuario"))
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        page.update()
    elif db.verificarCorreo(arregloCorreo):
        page.snack_bar = SnackBar(content=Text("Este correo ya esta en uso"))
        page.snack_bar.open = True
        page.update()
    else:
        nuevoLider = Lideres(nombre.value, apellido.value, arregloCedula, arregloTelefono, arregloCorreo, ubicacion.value, nivelUser.value)
        rutas.animar(formulario, contenedor1, contenedor2, page)

That's how I have structured the other validations, so what would be the most optimal way?
It would be of great help if you gave me an example, so I can guide myself and be able to change all the validations

Well, for the ones that are similar, you can do for control in (nombre, apellido, cedula, numTelefono, correo, ubicacion): / if not control.value: / control.error_text = mensaje.campoFaltante.

I tried it and it does the validation but it goes to the next form, and well the idea is that it doesn't let you go to the next form if the fields are empty

That seems like an entirely separate issue.  How are you supposed to stop the advancement to the next form?
